# How do I make this open without the user see it?

Tags: java, window, awt, javasound

I have the following code to open a media file:

```
public static void playMusic(File string, int time, String ProcessName) throws Exception {

    Desktop d1 = Desktop.getDesktop();
    d1.open(string);
    Thread.sleep(time + 500);
    kill(ProcessName);

}
```

Then I use:

```
playMusic(FILELOCATION, FILELENGTH, PROCESSNAME);
```

This will open the media file and play what ever is in it and then close. I was wondering if there was a way to make the media file window invisible when it comes up. I really don't won't the user to see the windows media window pop up everytime.

Comment: Then why do you use Desktop, why don't you use [**Clip**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/playing.html) instead?

Comment: *"could someone please post a sample of the clip api"*  You can see one in the [Java Sound info. page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info).

Answer (score 1):

I think that the best answer is "don't do it like that"

The whole point of `Desktop.open()` is to open the file on the user's desktop where the user can see it.  If you don't want the user to see it, don't do that.  In this case, you are better off either:

- trying to use the Java native sound APIs; e.g. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/playing.html, or
- firing up some external player application explicitly ... giving it the application specific options to hide the player's GUI.

---

In addition to the fact that using the desktop is conceptually the wrong approach, you are depending on the system / user binding your audio file type to an appropriate player tool.  That may be problematic on some platforms.  (Though to be honest, *this whole area* can be problematic if you use proprietary or patent-encumbered audio file formats.)

Comment: I am making a text adventure game with audio and it is proving to be harder than I though. Could someone please post a sample of the clip api so that I could understand. I'm getting errors like a mug!

Comment: Nevermind, after doing alittle research, I found out how to use it. Great help guys! Thx!